# "Абсолютно обо всём" — уточнение? Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения

Является ли "абсолютно обо всём" в данном предложении уточнением?

> Он не забыл рассказать обо всём, абсолютно обо всём(,) за три года своих странствий.

И какая пунктуация на месте скобок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, думаю, что *абсолютно обо всём* — это уточнение; запятая, конечно, нужна.

Однако, предложение по смыслу немного странное (опускаем уточнение):
*Он не забыл рассказать обо всём за три года своих странствий.*
Получается, что кто-то три года странствовал и все это время не забывал обо всём рассказывать.

Мне кажется, что предложение может иметь такой вид:
**Он не забыл рассказать обо всём, абсолютно обо всём, что видел за три года своих странствий.**
Или такой (со вставкой):
**Он не забыл рассказать обо всём — абсолютно обо всём, — что испытал за три года своих странствий.**

Вот похожий пример:
*— (...) Ваша главная задача — слежка. Наблюдать, анализировать, делать выводы и обо всем – абсолютно обо всем, Евгения Максимовна! — докладывать мне.*
М. Серова. Я подарю тебе все...

Answer (score 1):

Он не забыл рассказать обо всём, **абсолютно обо всём,** за три года своих своих странствий.

Да, это уточнение и по смыслу, и по структуре; интонация вставочная.

Собственно говоря, другого решения просто быть не может, так как отношения между дополнениями нельзя отнести ни к однородным (одна запятая), ни к неоднородным (нет запятых).

**Примечание**

Возможно, предложение лучше дополнить:

Он не забыл рассказать обо всём, абсолютно обо всём, что произошло за три года его странствий.